# Creating a numpy array from a loop

Tags: python, numpy, geocoding

I am trying to find a way of printing the minimum value from the loop below. The output is neither a list nor a numpy array (see output below). Also see my dataset, df, attached below.

**Code**

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df = pd.read_csv("dummy dataset.csv")

cities=['London','Edinburgh','Manchester']
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-application",timeout=None)
for city in cities:
    location = geolocator.geocode(city)

    df['GTC'] = df['height']*location.latitude + df['width']*location.longitude
    print(city,sum(df['GTC']))
```

**Result**

```
London  44060.839699659
Edinburgh   44707.029210128
Manchester  43565.213231322
```

I have tried code such as: `print("The smallest GTC is: ", min(sum(df['GTC'])))`

and trying to create an array with: `a = np.asarray(sum(df['GTC']))`

But neither of these solve the problem. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-sophisticated solution is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df = pd.read_csv("dummy dataset.csv")
cities=['London','Edinburgh','Manchester']
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-application",timeout=None)
mingtc = np.inf
mincity = 'unknown'
for city in cities:
    location = geolocator.geocode(city)
    gtc = sum(height*location.latitude + width*location.longitude)
    if gtc < mingtc:
        mingtc = gtc
        mincity = city
print(mincity, mingtc)
```

You could probably do something better using Pandas functionality, but it's unclear what the actual format of your dataframe is, or what location.latitude, location.longitude, height and width look like (are they floats, arrays, something else?). That makes it hard to show a more sophisticated approach.

The above solution works for the code you currently present in your question.

Comment: Just ran that (after changing height to df['height'] and width to df['width']), and get the following error:    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @MRHarv Yes, I just realised. I've added a `sum()` function, as in your code. Check again. At least the error tells us what location is (apparently, it's a dataframe, but `geopy` will be less known to people).

Comment: Note that `df['height']` and `df['width']` are not in your original question.